# How to replace all connections in a many-to-many relationship in Fauna

Tags: graphql, faunadb

Say I have this schema:

```graphql
Client {
 services: [Service] @relation(name: "ClientServices")
}
Service {
 clients: [Client] @relation(name: "ClientServices")
}
```

And I want to connect some services to a client, like this:

```graphql
mutation {
 updateClient(id: ..., data : {
   services:  {
     connect: ["123", "456"] ## where there are valid service _id's
  }
 }) { ... }
}
```

Fantastic. Works great.
But now I want to replace all the connections (services) with other ones, but still keep the 123 service.

```graphql
mutation {
 updateClient(id: ..., data : {
   services:  {
     connect: ["123", "789"] ## notice kept 123, and now want 789
  }
 }) { ... }
}
```

This will result in a `instance not unique` error from Fauna. Because its trying to connect 123 but its already in the ClientServices collection (the auto-generated collection that manages m-m relationships.)

**Is there an easy way to disconnect all and reconnect the ones I want in one call without a UDF?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can connect and disconnect in the same mutation (without a UDF):

```
mutation {
 updateClient(id: ..., data : {
   services:  {
     connect: ["789"],
     disconnect: ["456"]
  }
 }) { ... }
}
```

This assumes you have the ability to compute the diff on the client.  For example, using lodash:

```
const _filter = require('lodash/filter');
const _find = require('lodash/find');
const _map = require('lodash/map');

let orig = [{id: "123"}, {id: "456"}]
let replacements = [{id: "123"}, {id: "789"}]

let toConnect = _filter(replacements, o => !_find(orig, {id: o.id}))
let toDisconnect = _filter(orig, o => !_find(replacements, {id: o.id}))

mutate(
    // ...
    {
        connect: _map(toConnect, 'id'),
        disconnect: _map(toDisconnect, 'id')
    },
    // ...
)
```

As an easy solution for providing `replace` functionality, maybe the Fauna GQL API could provide some guarantees around order of operations.  If the `disconnect` is always performed before the `connect`, then you could always disconnect `orig` and connect `replacements`.  This guarantee seems reasonable, since I can't really imagine a sane reason for connecting and immediately disconnecting a relation in the same API call.

Comment: Thanks @colllin - I spent too long writing a UDF to replace.. and didn't think of combining the two (connect and disconnect). It works great!

Answer (score 1):

At this point, Fauna has create, disconnect and connect.
You seem to be looking for a **replace** that automatically calculates a diff and takes the correct actions in terms of disconnect and connect. I don't think that's currently possible with pure GraphQL. You would indeed need to write a UDF. It might be an interesting feature for others as well so it could be a good candidate for a feature request on the forums: https://forums.fauna.com/

Comment: Can't you just compute the diff in JS and send both the `disconnect` and `connect` fields in your GQL query?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, that was probably not entirely clear from my response. I assumed though that the user was looking for something where he doesn't have to compute it in the client.